# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client when use res.json

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I'm setting upload image with multer, multer-s3 but I want to response location file with res.json, an error occurs `Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

```
const upload = multer({ storage: 
  multerS3({
    s3,
    bucket: process.env.S3_BUCKET_NAME,
    key: function(req, file, cb) {
      return cb(null, `${Date.now().toString()}-${file.originalname}`)
    }
  })
})

const singleUpload = upload.single('image', 1)
```

Step 1:

`router.post('/upload', handlers.upload)`

```
upload: (req, res) => {
      singleUpload(req, res, function(error) {
        // console.log('----------------', req);
        if(error) {
          return 'Upload image false!!'
        }
        return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location})
      })
    }
```

=> Throw error.

Step 2:

```
router.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
      singleUpload(req, res, function(error) {
        if(error) {
          return 'Upload image false!!'
        }
        return res.json({'imageUrl': req.file.location})
      })
    })
```

=> good run

Someone can help me explain and clear this issue, thanks.

Comment: what does `singleUpload ` do?

Comment: @yarons i updated fn `singleUpload` above.